# Odd way to solve differential equations; is there a name for this approach?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found this approach to solving the equation $y'=y$ earlier today

[image]

Is there a name for this type of approach?

Comment: Which approach?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. The solution is now there

Comment: I propose to call it "The quirky Physician method". ^-^